# How to add a timestamp to bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I am running a script to check for security vulnerabilities. How do I add a timestamp to the script with results going into a file in /var/log/security-check

```
#!/bin/sh

# watch accounts - keep an eye on /etc/passwd,
#                  report if accounts change

secretcopy="$HOME/.watchdb"
tempfile="$HOME/.watchdb.new"
passwd="/etc/passwd"
compare=0               # by default, don't compare

trap "/bin/rm -f $tempfile" 0

if [ -s "$secretcopy" ] ; then
  lastrev="$(cat $secretcopy)"
  compare=1
fi

cat $passwd | cut -d: -f1 > $tempfile

current="$(cat $tempfile)"

if [ $compare -eq 1 ] ; then
  if [ "$current" != "$lastrev" ] ; then
    echo "WARNING: password file has changed"
    diff $secretcopy $tempfile | grep '^[<>]' |
        sed 's/</Removed: /;s/>/Added:/'
  fi
else
   mv $tempfile $secretcopy
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: The script should already be timestamped, every file usually is. If you want a log of when the script was run (not sure if that is what you mean), then you can do `echo $(date) >> /var/log/security-check`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Every file when modified gets timestamped. You can do a `ls -l` to check that. Also if you need to timestamp any file, just use `touch`. `touch <script_name>` creates if it doesn’t exist. If it exists, timestamp of that script that you passed to it will be updated to latest time.

Comment: Thank you. The log is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @I'L'I : Why do you want to _echo_ here? `data >>/var/log/cecurity-check` would do as well.

Answer (score 1):

Every file when modified gets timestamped. You can do a `ls -l` to check that. Also if you need to timestamp any file, just use touch. touch  creates if it doesn’t exist. If it exists, timestamp of that script that you passed to it will be updated to latest time.

If you want to add time stamp to a file separately, use:

```
date +"%T” > "filename"
```

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/387042/how-to-check-all-timestamps-of-a-file) post adds some more detail to the answer.

If you want to get a file to be stamped to latest time:

```
touch filename
```